# How to read a file and write into a text file?

Tags: file-io, vb6

I want to open mis file, copy all the data and write into a text file.

My mis file.

File name – 1.mis

```
M3;3395;44;0;1;;20090404;094144;8193;3;0;;;;
M3;3397;155;0;2;;20090404;105941;8193;3;0;;;;
M3;3396;160;0;1;;20090404;100825;8193;3;0;;;;
M3;3398;168;0;2;;20090404;110106;8193;3;0;;;;
```

so on...,

The above data should appear in a text file with same file name (1.txt).

I tried this code.

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim iFileNo As Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\Clockings.mis" For Input As #iFileNo
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
Input #iFileNo, sFileText
Loop
Close #iFileNo

Open "C:\Clients\Converter\2.txt" For Output As #iFileNo
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
Write #iFileNo, sFileText
Loop
Close #iFileNo
```

Nothing is saved in 1.txt.

Comment: Well, if your mis file stores it's data as text, you could just copy the file to 1.txt... :-)

Comment: There's nothing in 1.txt because you're writing to 2.txt...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It far easier to use the scripting runtime which is installed by default on Windows

Just go project Reference and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime and click OK.

Then you can use this code which is way better than the default file commands

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream
Dim TempS As String
Dim Final As String
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Clients\Converter\Clockings.mis", ForReading)
'Use this for reading everything in one shot
Final = TS.ReadAll
'OR use this if you need to process each line
Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
    TempS = TS.ReadLine
    Final = Final & TempS & vbCrLf
Loop
TS.Close

Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Clients\Converter\2.txt", ForWriting, True)
    TS.Write Final
TS.Close
Set TS = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

As for what is wrong with your original code here you are reading each line of the text file.

```
Input #iFileNo, sFileText
```

Then here you write it out

```
Write #iFileNo, sFileText
```

sFileText is a string variable so what is happening is that each time you read, you just replace the content of sFileText with the content of the line you just read.

So when you go to write it out, all you are writing is the last line you read, which is probably a blank line.

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim sFinal as String
Dim iFileNo As Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\Clockings.mis" For Input As #iFileNo
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
  Input #iFileNo, sFileText
sFinal = sFinal & sFileText & vbCRLF
Loop
Close #iFileNo

iFileNo = FreeFile 'Don't assume the last file number is free to use
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\2.txt" For Output As #iFileNo
Write #iFileNo, sFinal
Close #iFileNo
```

Note you don't need to do a loop to write. sFinal contains the complete text of the File ready to be written at one shot. Note that input reads a LINE at a time so each line appended to sFinal needs to have a CR and LF appended at the end to be written out correctly on a MS Windows system. Other operating system may just need a LF (Chr$(10)).

If you need to process the incoming data then you need to do something like this.

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim sFinal as String
Dim vTemp as Variant
Dim iFileNo As Integer
Dim C as Collection
Dim R as Collection
Dim I as Long
Set C = New Collection
Set R = New Collection

iFileNo = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\Clockings.mis" For Input As #iFileNo
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
  Input #iFileNo, sFileText
  C.Add sFileText
Loop
Close #iFileNo

For Each vTemp in C
     Process vTemp
Next sTemp

iFileNo = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\2.txt" For Output As #iFileNo
For Each vTemp in R
   Write #iFileNo, vTemp & vbCRLF
Next sTemp
Close #iFileNo
```

Comment: Some user computers don't have FileSystemObject (I have experienced this). I think overzealous IT departments sometimes trample on the scripting runtime for fear of viruses

Comment: Yes which is why you should include as part of your install. The sysop can then decide whether to make an exception for the application. Or  make your own version wrapping the native function or wrap the .NET equivalent up. Both of which are overkill IMO.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it line by line:

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim iInputFile As Integer, iOutputFile as integer

iInputFile = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\Clockings.mis" For Input As #iInputFile 
iOutputFile = FreeFile
Open "C:\Clients\Converter\2.txt" For Output As #iOutputFile 
Do While Not EOF(iInputFile)
   Line Input #iInputFile , sFileText
   ' sFileTextis a single line of the original file
   ' you can append anything to it before writing to the other file
   Print #iOutputFile, sFileText 
Loop
Close #iInputFile 
Close #iOutputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileCopy "1.mis", "1.txt"
```

Comment: Filecopy is working, Suppose i want to add something in a destination text file, How to make code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    An example of reading a file:
Dim sFileText as String
Dim iFileNo as Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
'open the file for reading
Open "C:\Test.txt" For Input As #iFileNo
'change this filename to an existing file! (or run the example below first)

'read the file until we reach the end
Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)
Input #iFileNo, sFileText
'show the text (you will probably want to replace this line as appropriate to your program!)
MsgBox sFileText
Loop

'close the file (if you dont do this, you wont be able to open it again!)
Close #iFileNo
(note: an alternative to Input # is Line Input # , which reads whole lines).


An example of writing a file:
Dim sFileText as String
Dim iFileNo as Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
'open the file for writing
Open "C:\Test.txt" For Output As #iFileNo
'please note, if this file already exists it will be overwritten!

'write some example text to the file
Print #iFileNo, "first line of text"
Print #iFileNo, " second line of text"
Print #iFileNo, "" 'blank line
Print #iFileNo, "some more text!"

'close the file (if you dont do this, you wont be able to open it again!)
Close #iFileNo
```

From [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-342619.html)

Comment: See, @Gopal: Above Same **data’s** should appear in a text file with same. He/She needs a FileCopy.

Comment: @Khenu - In a source file am having n number of lines, How to make a code?