# How can I remove a line of text from a text file in VB6?

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a file and write into a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404758/how-to-read-a-file-and-write-into-a-text-file)

I have a search facility where items are displayed in a ListView. These items are read in from a file. When I select an item in the ListView I want to be able to remove it from the text file as well.
At the moment, it is is only removed from the ListView but when I search again it still displays so it isn't being deleted from the text file.

Basically my program is a list of products with their barcodes and quantities. The user can search for an item, which is displayed in the listview, then edit it to add or reduce the quantity. When they click save it is written to the file. That is all working fine, but it is now showing the item twice, same barcode and product name and different quantities.

I tried to use the replace function but that is just adding empty lines of text to my file.
I have also gotten advice to copy the file and remove the selected item. I'm unsure how to do this. Does anyone have any alternative ways to do this? 
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
Dim barcode As String
Dim prodNum As String
Dim unknown As String
Dim desc As String
Dim size As String
Dim costPrice As String
Dim retailPrice As String
Dim deptCode As String
Dim dept As String
Dim subDeptCode As String
Dim subDept As String
Dim quantity As String
Dim barcodeYes As String
Dim Number As String
Dim i As Single

ListView1.ListItems.Remove ListView1.SelectedItem.Index

Open "D:\VB\EXPORT PRODUCT FILE.CSV" For Input As #3
Input #3, barcode, prodNum, unknown, desc, size, costPrice, retailPrice, deptCode, dept,      subDeptCode, subDept, quantity, barcodeYes, Number
AddQuantity.Show
AddQuantity.txtName.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem
AddQuantity.txtBarcode.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)
AddQuantity.txtQuantity.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)
Close #3
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only way to remove something from the middle of a file is to rewrite eveything from that point onwards.

You haven't showed your code to write to the file but I assume you're appending.
You'll need to change this to load all data, change the entry you want then save it all again.

Alternatively, use a database which is designed for this kind of use.

Comment: Thanks Deanna. Yeah I am appending. This is going onto the next form but whatever would be highlighted in the listView is what I would want to be deleted from the text file. So how would I go about changing the entry and saving the whole file again?

Comment: See the question LittleBobbyTables [marked this as a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1404758/588306).