# Manipulate a text file line by line using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file in which I must modify some lines with some values from a Excel Worsheet.

The way I do it:
I open the text in VBA and I loop each line. If the line matches my criterias, I replace it and save it to a new file, but if it doesn't interest me, I just save the line to a new file without any modifications.
The problem is that when I save the lines which doesn't concern me, I loose the format of those lines - this happens only to the lines which contains at least one number.

For example: This line

```
1          2     3
```

Will become:

```
1
2
3
```

This is the way I loop each line:

```
Open Path For Input As #1 
Do Until EOF(1)     
Input #1, ReadData
If not flag then
File.WriteLine (ReadData) 
else
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. The reconstruction of the line in my program is not a solution, because the format of the lines differs.

Comment: Use Print and not Write.  Also need to add back the line breaks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405227/3198973) for a good example of how to handle file io in vba.

Comment: @Tim Williams - the problem is not the way I write in the file, but the way I read the file. Instead of Input, I should've use Line Input. Anw, 10x to you I found the solution.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I will check your link for future answers. 10x

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I've used the Input way to read the file.

So when I used the Input way: "With the Input statement data values are read as list of variables". Because of this, I didn't read the whole line, but only the first number.

So I used the Line Input:  with the Line Input statement all the data are read as a single string

This is where I found the solutionL: http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2012/06/excel-vba-read-and-write-text-files.html